# Python web scraper will not work on deeply nested tags

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping, python-re

This is my second week of coding in Python. I wanted to write a scraper that would return a location and its phone number for all locations. The scraper is incomplete and I have tried a few versions but they all return either an empty list `[]` or an error.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

webpage_response = requests.get('https://www.orangetheory.com/en-us/locations/')

webpage = webpage_response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, "html.parser")

soup.find_all(attrs={'class': 'aria-label'})
```

Answer (score 1):

To get info about all fitness clubs in USA from that page you can use next example:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://api.orangetheory.co/partners/v2/studios?country=United%20States&sort=studioName"

data = requests.get(url).json()
df = pd.DataFrame([d[0] for d in data["data"]])
df = pd.concat([df, df.pop("studioLocation").apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)

print(df)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Prints:

```
      studioId                            studioUUId  mboStudioId                                  studioName studioNumber                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              description        studioStatus             openDate           reOpenDate   taxRate                                                                                                                                logoUrl                                   contactEmail              timeZone environment                                   studioProfiles                                       physicalAddress               physicalCity         physicalState physicalPostalCode                     physicalRegion  physicalCountryId physicalCountry     phoneNumber      latitude      longitude
0         2266  f627d35c-9e2b-452a-8017-bfbcccff5a4d     610952.0                             14th Street, DC         0943  The science of excess post-exercise oxygen consumption(EPOC) takes your results to new heights in this exciting group fitness concept. You will feel new energy and see amazing results with only 2-4 workouts per week. Each 60-minute class is broken into intervals of high-energy cardiovascular training and strength training. Use a variety of equipment including treadmills, rowing machines, suspension training, and free weights to tone your body and gain energy throughout the day. Exciting and inspiring group classes motivate you to beat plateaus and stick to your goals. Pay-as-you-go or get deep discounts with customized packages.\r\n\r\nThe best part of the Orange Experience is the results. You can burn calories for up to 38 hours after your workout!              Active  2017-09-02 00:00:00  2020-06-27 00:00:00  0.000000                 https://clients.mindbodyonline.com/studios/OrangetheoryFitnessWashingtonDC0943/logo_mobile.png?imageversion=1513008044      studiomanager0943@orangetheoryfitness.com      America/New_York        PROD     {'isWeb': 1, 'introCapacity': 1, 'isCrm': 1}                           1925 14th Street NW Suite C                 Washington  District of Columbia              20009                              DC-01                  1   United States      2028691700   38.91647339   -77.03197479
1        47914  01ddd24d-58bf-4959-bcb2-34587d6e48fc     660917.0                         2021 Virtual Summit        10001                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     None         Coming Soon                 None                 None  0.000000                                                                                                                                   None     studiomanager10001@orangetheoryfitness.com      America/New_York        PROD     {'isWeb': 0, 'introCapacity': 0, 'isCrm': 0}                                                     *                          *                     *                  *                              NV-01                  1   United States                  -81.66339500   -15.58054000
2         2964  9fd74853-4bad-4f1d-a9c7-fcbf27eb1651     576312.0                                 Abilene, TX         0862                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     None              Active  2018-09-22 00:00:00  2020-05-18 00:00:00  0.000000                                                                                                                                   None      studiomanager0862@orangetheoryfitness.com       America/Chicago        PROD     {'isWeb': 1, 'introCapacity': 1, 'isCrm': 1}                                    3950 Catclaw Drive                    Abilene                 Texas              79606                              TX-06                  1   United States      3254006191   32.40399933   -99.77462006
3         3139  2a5a5bc7-ea4a-4a2a-b166-56ce5e6ee7e2     415638.0                                     Acworth         1188                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     None              Active  2019-04-17 00:00:00  2020-05-17 00:00:00  0.000000                                                                                                                                   None      studiomanager1188@orangetheoryfitness.com      America/New_York        PROD     {'isWeb': 1, 'introCapacity': 1, 'isCrm': 1}                   4391 Acworth Dallas Rd NW Suite 212                    Acworth               Georgia              30101                              GA-01                  1   United States      7706748722   34.05842590   -84.72319794

...
```

and saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Comment: ahhh. awesome. Thanks so much!